# How Can I use POST http method with Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I use this Command in fetch  in Service Worker

```
 if (event.request.method =='POST') {

        event.respondWith(fetch(event.request,{method: 'post'}));
        return;
    }
```

but I get this error :

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request whose mode is 'navigate' and a non-empty RequestInit.

What should I do ?

Comment: What 's the type of event?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the sample code that you provide, it looks like you want to just implement the default, pretend-like-there's-no-service-worker behavior when you handle `fetch` event for a `POST` request.

The easiest way to do that is to simply not call `event.respondWith()` in the first place. Calling `event.respondWith()` is optional, and if you don't call it in a `fetch` handler, the service worker will look for any other registered `fetch` handlers and give them a chance to respond.

If none of the `fetch` event handlers respond, then the request will be fulfilled via either the browser cache (depending on the request headers and state of the cache) or the network, exactly as if there were no service worker involvement.

If, for some reason, you really need to call `event.respondWith(), but you want to mimic the default behavior, then using

```
event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
```

should work, i.e. leave out the `{method: 'post'}` bit. The `event.request` already knows that it's a `POST`, so it's not necessary to pass anything else in to `fetch()` in order to tell it that.